# Maximum length between two similar elements in an array

Tags: c++

How can I find the maximum length between two similar elements in an array?

`{6, 6, 4, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4}`

from this array the maximum length between two 6's
 is `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` not `{4, 2, 3}`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code.

Comment: Think you have to do this is time-complexity O(n2). Just loop over each element and set a distance every time you encounter the same number, when it is found the next time you just write over the last distance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is to find maximum length of the subarray that only has unique elements.

This can obviously done in O(n*n) if you choose a range from i ... j and update max length if the subarray doesn't have duplicates.

```
max_len = 0
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) 
        max_len = max( len(arr[i ... j] ), max_len) if arr[i ... j] has unique elements
```

We can optimize the above code by storing the last occurance of each number and finding the distance based on it.

```
int find_max_length(vector<int> arr) {
        map<int, int> last_occ; //store the last occurance of each number
        int n = arr.size();

        //initialize last occurance as -1
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
            last_occ[arr[i] ] = -1;

        //store the starting position of the subarray that has unique numbers
        int unique_pos = 0, max_length = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if(last_occ[arr[i] ] != -1) // the number can't be a part of the subarray since a copy of it exists. Trackback subarray
                unique_pos = last_occ[arr[i] ] + 1;

            //all elements from unique_pos to the current index will be unique
            max_length = max(max_length, i - unique_pos + 1);
            last_occ[arr[i] ] = i;  
        }

    return max_length; 
}
```

You can make the program return the range of the index and print the numbers that are part of the max_length by making a slight modification.

This one runs in O(n)*log(n) since fetching from `map` is log n